# Reduce CPU usage by using sleep

Tags: swift, multithreading

I'm taking snapshots from AR view 30 times per sec and sending it on another vc to process, the cpu usage goes eventually until 280% and the device gets too hot and the performance decrease and then I have frame drops.
I'm thinking of using `Thread.sleep` to make the thread sleep for 1 sec in every minutes, my question is, do you think it's a good approach? does it have any effects at all to reduce CPU usage or cool down the phone a bit? Or there is another better way?

If the thread sleep for 1 sec in 1 min, doesn't matter much for me.

Thank you so much

Comment: Use timer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/replacing-foundation-timers-with-timer-publishers

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not using Timer. I added Thread.sleep in session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)

Comment: Bad idea. Thread.sleep does not solve performance issues: first of all you are not reducing the workload, merely make things slower. Also sleep is blocking the thread, so system has less threads to work with, while workload remains the same, so you are actually increasing load on other threads.
Instead consider throttling your requests, for example drop frame rate from 30 to 3 or so (since you are ready to sleep for 1 second, why not then process 3 frames per second? human eye won't notice anything below 0.5 sec anyways)

Comment: Blocking the delegate thread could cause side effects I’d think. Come to think about it, setting up a chain of publishers could work really well here. .debounce, .drop might work.

Comment: Hard to say anything without any code, but also processing 30 frames per second may not be your issue: _what your processing of the frame_ does may be more important. Is everything in that processing pipeline really needed 30 times a second, and is that processing optimized? It can be a giant difference between "process frame somehow" and "process frame in optimal way".

Comment: @jjquirckart, thank you so much, so you think if I reduce the frame rate to 3fps per sec for about 1 or 2 sec in 1 min, could reduce the load?

Comment: @jjquirckart Thanks again
Here you can see the codes, I asked another questions, but no one responded me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72596318/snapshoting-from-an-ar-view-using-multi-threading

Comment: I kind of answered above. I'd make sure first that single frame processing is sort of "optimal" (very much depends what it does), and then see if frame reduction is even needed. Because you can reduce frames by 10 times, but improving poor processing may improve your perf 1000 times...

Comment: @jjquirckart Thanks, I would be so grateful if you can see another my questions, I added the code there, and you can see what I did, I stuck in this part for a few weeks

Comment: I doubt, just pausing 1 out of 60 seconds would  make that much of a difference, if for the other 59 seconds in that minute you are doing inefficient work

Comment: Use the profiler - it's perfect for cases like this...

Comment: For example your `pushARframe` is creating `SCNRenderer` every time. Is that neccessary? May not be the main issue, but still. Also why do you do the whole processing on main thread? Seems to me only `this.sceneView.scene` requires to be done on main thread, and the rest of the work can be pushed elsewhere...

Comment: Thank you so much, will do those things, and by somewhere else, the background thread will be a good one?